# String length Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

As a mandatory validation, I check if my textfield is empty via this method:

```
- (NSString *) clean: (NSString *) str
{
    return [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

and while inserting in Database:

```
if([self clean:textfield.text].length == 0)
{
//Error
}
```

I was wondering if I have to use <= 0 ? to prevent some kind of fishy bug/error later on. Like we have in Websites(SQL injection and others). Can someone insert a negative length string in a textfield in iOS APP ?

Comment: That method looks like it would live quite nicely as a category as opposed to attached to some arbitrary class

Answer (score 2):

```
NSSTring *text = [textfield.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 if ([text length] == 0 )
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please    enter text." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

**IT will check whether the textfield is empty or not !!!!!!!**

Comment: What is the point of calling `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` just to see if the text field is empty or not?

Answer (score 2):

According to apple documentation, the prototype of length method is :

```
- (NSUInteger)length
```

Handle the negative values is then not necessary (you have an unsigned return value), so " == 0" is ok for testing.